# Как из одной формы обратиться к элементу dataGridView принадлежащему другой форме

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Есть 2 формы. На одной из них расположен элемент dataGridView. Как из второй формы обратиться к нему?!

Answer (score 2):

Используем свойство 'родитель'
При создании второй формы устанавливаем владельца

```
Form2 f = new Form2();
f.Owner = this;
f.ShowDialog();
```

Во второй форме определяем владельца

```
Form1 main = this.Owner as Form1;
if(main != null)
{
    string s = main.textBox1.Text;
    main.textBox1.Text = "OK";
}
```

- Доступ ко всем открытым полям/функциям первой формы
- Передача данных возможна в обе стороны
- Не нарушает ООП

Источник: http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread110436.html

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность ).

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky, ну не заниматься же копипастом? Тем более на стеке нет нормального редактора, чтобы перенести такое форматирование. Там тема уже 5 лет висит, никто не удалил.

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky, по поводу "минимальный необходимый пример". Лично мое мнение - лучше дать полноценный пример (пусть даже он будет по ссылке), чем навязывать автору вопроса свое мнение, предоставив только один конкретный пример.

Comment: Основная идея в том, чтобы ответ был самодостаточным.

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky, поправил. Но считаю это не совсем правильны. Сделайте нормальный редактор - будут хорошие, отформатированные ответы.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду рад увидеть Ваше предложение о редакторе на [Мете](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 1):

Вам **не должно** хотеться из одного элемента представления залезть в несвязанный другой элемент. Если вам такое захотелось, ваша бизнес-логика вшита в UI-код, а это неправильно.

Ваша архитектура должна быть устроена по-другому. Вы должны разделять контент и представление.

1. `DataGridView` на первой форме есть представление некоторых данных. Эти данные находятся в модели или VM, или в коде, отвечающем за контент. Но любом случае **не** в коде, отвечающем за представление.
2. Другая форма представляет пользователю другие данные. Все необходимые данные для второй формы находятся тут.
3. Бизнес-логика копирует данные, соответствующие первой форме, к данным, соответствующим второй форме. Или у этих данных есть ссылка на общие данные. Здесь точный рецепт зависит от *смысла* этих данных.

Таким образом, каждая из форм знает лишь данные, адресованные ей, и не должна подглядывать за другими формами. Заодно в приложении появилась архитектура.

Профит!