# Передача данных с Form2 в Form1

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Здравствуйте товарищи знатоки.
Сегодня постала задача: существует вторичная форма Form2, в этой форме 2 элемента textBox и кнопка.
Так вот. Задача полагается в том что я должен ввести в тем поля textBox какие-то числа, а эти числа должны передаться в переменную Формы1 и по нажатию кнопку в Форме1 сама же Форма1 должна измениться свой размер (Высоту и Ширину)

Как по кнопке сменить высоту и ширину я знаю, я не знаю как передать данные с Формы2 в Форму1

Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Особо показывать нечего 
Я в главной форме подключил вторичную

```
#include"Form2.h"
```

По кнопке в элементе MenuStrip я вызываю Форму2

```
private: System::Void inpitSizeToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             Form2^ form2 = gcnew Form2;
             form2->ShowDialog();
```

В Форме2 у меня 2 текстовых поля где я вписываю ШИРИНУ и ВЫСОТУ главной формы и по нажатию кнопки в Форме2 эти числа что записаны в текстовых полях должны изменить размер главной формы.
Я пробовал так: 
Подключил в Форме2 Форму1

```
#include"Form1.h"
```

Но тут после перестройки проекта срхзу поплыли ошибки о том что Form2 это не объявленный идентификатор.

Я попробовал в главной форме вызвать поля с Формы2 таким методом

```
Form2::textBox1->Text=Width;
```

Но получил ошибку: 
**выражение слева от "->Text" должно указывать на тип класса, структуры или объединения либо на универсальный тип**

Comment: у вас чистый С++? или С++ CLI? Для С++ CLI в правой секции страницы есть несколько отвеченных вариантов вашего вопроса. выбирайте на свой вкус.

Comment: Хмм.. 
Искал я, но ничего такого не нашел. В одной из тем было написано чтобы в Форме2 надо было подключить Форму1. Вот так: #include"Form1.h" 

Но после перестройеки проекта было много ошибок что Форма2 это не объявленный идентификатор

Comment: так покажите минимальный код того, что вы уже пробовали - вам помогут его до рабочего состояния довести.

Comment: [Дубликат](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/426295/10105)?

Comment: Показывать особо нечего. Мне кажется что я делаю большую и очень глупую ошибку. И даже не одну

Comment: @VladD, нет, тут ShowDialog, все проще

Comment: @VladD но это на шарпе написано. Я много манов находил, но только на шарпе. На с++ как будто отрезали

Comment: @PashaPash: Но общий принцип тот же вроде?

Comment: @razorqhex: Потому что (1) надо писать не на c++/cli, а на шарпе, и (2) не на WinForms, а на WPF.

Comment: @VladD - если ТС пойдет по вашей ссылке - он начнет дергать первую форму из второй. что плохо.

Comment: @VladD по заданию надо на С++ Windows Forms

Comment: @razorqhex: языком c++/cli не пользуется никто в пределах экспериментальной погрешности. Этот язык не предназначен для серьёзной работы. Он нужен лишь как прокладка между нативным и .net-кодом для сложных случаев.

Comment: @PashaPash: Я ссылался не на вопрос, а на ответ. (По крайней мере, свой.) А там говорится, что надо действовать через модель/VM.

Comment: @razorqhex: Интересно, это один и тот же вуз или нет? Не расскажете, в каком вузе такие преподаватели?

Comment: @VladD извините конечно, но не могу. Не хочу чтобы весь интернет узнал о "таком" вузе

Что же.. Спасибо за ответы . Примусь писать на шарпе

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24257/discussion-on-question-by-razorqhex----form2--form1).

Answer (score 1):

Вы подходите к решению не с той стороны. Вызов `ShowDialog` блокирует выполнение кода в обработчике до тех пор, пока первая форма не будет закрыта. т.е. когда код продолжит выполнение - в полях второй формы будут введенные пользователем значения.

Т.е. вам нужно

- объявить во второй форме свойство, которое вернет выбранную ширину (и еще одно - для высоты).
- в теле свойства возвращать значение из текстбокса
- в коде обработчика на первой форме, сразу после `ShowDialog`, доставать из формы2 значение этого свойства и менять ширину (высоту).