# как получить данные из Form1

Tags: c#, winforms

есть две формы, в первой dataGridView который заполняется из БД

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConnectToBD();
        RefreshMainWindow();
    }
    //Обновить главное окно программы
    public void RefreshMainWindow()
    {
        //crossTable.Rows.Clear();
        //ConnectToBD();

        string year = "";
        string que2 = "";
        string que = "SELECT Year FROM GDP.dbo.Years ORDER BY Year";
        SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(que, GlobalVars.conn);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adap.Fill(ds, "Year");

        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["Year"].Rows)
        {
            year = year + "[" + Convert.ToString(dr["Year"]) + "],";
        }
        if (year != "")
        {
            year = year.Substring(0, year.Length - 1);
            que2 = "SELECT Страна, " + year +
                         " FROM " +
                         "(SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT GDP.dbo.Lands.Land as 'Страна', GDP.dbo.Years.Year as 'Год', GDP.dbo.GDPValues.GDPValue as 'Значение' " +
                         "FROM GDP.dbo.GDPValues INNER JOIN " +
                         "GDP.dbo.Lands ON GDP.dbo.GDPValues.ID_Land = GDP.dbo.Lands.ID_Land INNER JOIN " +
                         "GDP.dbo.Years ON GDP.dbo.GDPValues.ID_Year = GDP.dbo.Years.ID_Year) data " +
                         "PIVOT " +
                         "(sum (Значение) for Год in  ( " + year + ")) as mytabl";
        }
        else
        {
            que2 = "SELECT dbo.Lands.Land AS Cтрана FROM dbo.Lands";
        }

        adap = new SqlDataAdapter(que2, GlobalVars.conn);

        ds = new DataSet();

        DataTable Dist = new DataTable();
        Dist.Columns.Add("Страна");

        adap.Fill(ds, "mytabl");

        crossTable.DataSource = ds.Tables["mytabl"];           

    }
```

Во второй форме

```
    private void Load_Graf_Default()
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        label4.Text = f1.crossTable.RowCount.ToString();
    }
    private void btn_Refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        Load_Graf_Default();
    }
```

все бы ничего но когда я спрашиваю из второй формы есть ли в dataGV данные то говорит что там ничего нет. строки, столбцы по нулям.

Comment: А как спрашиваете?

Comment: Form1 f1 = new Form1();
       label4.Text = f1.dataGV.RowCount.ToString();

Comment: Обращаетесь к `dataGV` прямо сразу после создания формы что ли? Или код, который вы привели в вопросе, находится в конструкторе формы? Еще проверьте, что, данные действительно возвращаются запросом.

Comment: при загрузке первой формы загружается и dataGV, потом кнопкой открываю вторую форму и также кнопкой пытаюсь в label узнать кол-во строк в dataGV

Comment: Добавьте полный код в вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: Собственно загружает в OnLoad обработчике, но его не вызываете, потому что не показываете форму, а просто при вызове конструктора это событие не вызывается

Comment: и к чему мне тогда обращаться?

Comment: @Zakat, а зачем вам форма если вы ее не показываете?

Comment: к сожалению я не знаю как по другому обратиться к элементу в ней

Comment: @Zakat, мне кажется стоит просто вынести этот запрос в отдельный класс, который потом можно будет использовать и в первой форме и во второй форме

Comment: @Grundy: Вангую, что у ТС есть видимая на экране форма, а чтобы получить данные, он создаёт _второй экземпляр_. И не понимнает, почему во втором экземпляре нету данных из первого.

Comment: @VladD, такое тоже не исключено, а еще есть вариант, что просто _весь код_ в формах

Comment: @Grundy ну уж не настолько я... 
нашел решение
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426295/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83-datagridview-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC

Comment: @Zakat, честно говоря не знаю как ответ по ссылке вам подойдет :) там вызывается `ShowDialog`, То есть форма показывается а у вас нет

Comment: эм... не... вторая форма по кнопочке открывается, все норм)) просто у меня там не было
        f.Owner = this;
ну во вторую форму дописал
       Form1 main = this.Owner as Form1;